# Use same layout for multiple RecyclerView's with different orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I got 2 `RecyclerView`s both using same layout.xml file in `ViewHolder`

I set a static `layout_width` which works fine for horizontal scrolling RecyclerView, xml code below

```
rvFirst.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

[image]

But 2nd vertically scrolling RecyclerView, where width of cell is not covering the parent,

**is it possible** to use same layout file as below and be able to change `layout_width` to match/fill parent?

[image]

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            tools:text="Title"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Description"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I can pass `isVertical: Boolean` parameter to both Adapter and ViewHolder, but I have no idea where I should change the layout

```
class CustomAdapter(val items: ArrayList<Item>, val isVertical: Boolean = false): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, p0, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(view, isVertical)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CustomViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        items.getOrNull(p1)?.let {
            p0.bindData(it)
        }
    }
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View, isVertical: Boolean) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private val tvTitle: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle)
    private val tvDescrip: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescrip)

    fun bindData(item: Item) {
        tvTitle.text = "Title"
        tvDescrip.text = "Description"
    }
}
```

Comment: you can take two recyclerview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to change `layout_width` by overriding `onCreateViewHolder` of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, like so

```
class CustomAdapter(val items: ArrayList<Item>, val isVertical: Boolean = false): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, p0, false)
        if (isVertical) {
            view.setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        }
        return CustomViewHolder(view)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your viewholder , you have to test the orientation (you can pass it as variable to your adapter)
and then :

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, p0, false)
if(isVertical){
// width,height
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}else{
// Here you need to use your 250dp,
// You have to convert the code to Kotlin
float width = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._150sdp);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
// No need to pass isVertical to the view holder
return CustomViewHolder(view, isVertical)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, this is exactly what I want, just can you tell me which method I should override to use your code? I edited my post to include `CustomViewHolder`, I am also able to pass `isVertical` variable

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/separator"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            tools:text="Title"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Description"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

in in adapter...

in vertical `recyclerview` use this

```
llMain.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
llMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

in horizontal `recyclerview` use this

```
 llMain.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 llMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```